# Cuando trato de actualizar datos de un registro PHP lo elimina por completo

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una información en una tabla, cuando trato de cambiar los datos de un campo en un registro, PHP elimina el registro por completo. Por ejemplo, tengo la siguiente tabla denominada "finanzas" con los siguientes registros:
[antes de actualizar la tabla](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NE47e.png)

Le aplico el siguiente código:
[cpodigo PHP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FIWk.png)

y en vez de actualizar el registro 7, lo elimina, obteniendo finalmente una tabla con 6 registros.
[después de actualizar la tabla](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64Ut2.png)

El código PHP es correcto, la consulta en MySQL es correcta, pero el resultado no es el esperado. Posiblemente se trate de la configuración de la base de datos o de la tabla. Espero solución. Gracias.

El código de creación de la tabla es el siguiente:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `finanzas` (
`record` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`mov` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`id` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_spanish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`rtte` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_spanish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`destinat` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_spanish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`id_mat` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_spanish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`estatus` varchar(5) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_spanish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`motivo` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_spanish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`descriptor` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_spanish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`importe` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
`importepesos` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
`importebtc` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`fee` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
`fee_pasarela` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
`date_reg` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`date_pago` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`pasarela` varchar(80) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_spanish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`folio` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_spanish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`tipo` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_spanish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`tipoadm` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_spanish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`notas` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_spanish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`clabe` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_spanish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`nivel` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`centinela` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`record`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_spanish_ci;

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]  Tienes una lectura obligatoria  [ask]  .

Comment: Falta mucha información en tu pregunta, sobretodo si dices que puede ser algo de la base de datos o de la tabla, como mínimo necesitariamos la estructura de la tabla (la instrucción CREATE de la misma para ser mas específico). El tema de que nos pongas imágenes del código tampoco nos vale, tienes que poner el codigo escrito para que podamos copiarlo, y las imagenes adjuntarlas directamente a la pregunta y no dejarlas como enlaces. Te edito la pregunta arreglando las imagenes para que veas como tiene que quedar.

Comment: Muy extraño. ¿No será que estás llamando realmente a otro código que hace un `DELETE` y crees estar llamando al código de `UPDATE`? Eso es muy fácil de saber, retorna un mensaje que ponga algo como: `"Se ejecutó la sentencia UPDATE"` y así saldremos de dudas en ese sentido. Otra cosa es que puede haber algún `TRIGGER` que se dispara, o cuestiones de integridad referencial, pero, según dices, el problema ocurre en la misma tabla, no en tablas dependientes de ella, por lo que esa posibilidad queda descartada. Y, como ya dijo @Marc, considera poner el texto del código, no imágenes.

Comment: Puse imágenes en mi pregunta ya que el código total es muy complejo como para postearlo aquí, todo se origina en la petición de un formulario, petición que es validada por javascript desde el cliente, posteriormente la orden se tranfiere a un archivo PHP en el servidor que elije la clase de acuerdo a la petición. Dentro de la clase está el procedimiento que realiza la actualización. He hecho pruebas anulando el código UPDATE para comprobar si por equivocación llamo a un DELETE, pero no es así, cuando anulo el código UPDATE, el sistema no hace nada, luego entonces no hay bifurcación errónea.